# How to break out of an assert in iOS / swift

Tags: ios, swift, assert, lldb

I've hit an assertion in code and wondering if there's a way to create a wrapper around the assert that would enable breaking out and continuing execution or some other function that would enable a way to suppress the assert through the lldb debugger.

`assert(condition(), makeCriticalEvent().event.description, file: fileID, line: UInt(line))`

This is the standard assertion in apples libraries [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/assert(_:_:file:line:)). When I hit this assertion I tried continuing execution but it stays stuck at the assertion. I'd like to silence the assertion (likely through the lldb debugger by typing some command). Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Remove it (or comment it out) then if you don't want it.

Comment: Can you clarify your question.  Why are you adding an assertion and then wanting to ignore it?  Is it a valid assertion, in which case resolve the issue, or if it's not get rid of it?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, yes that's the easiest way but that involves rebuilding the app. With a small app that's no problem but I'm working on a large app that can take a minute or more to rebuild.

Comment: @flanker, in a large organization there are many people working on different aspects of the code. One might put in an assert that another engineer has no knowledge about. I want to ignore it as it's not related to what I'm working on

Comment: You make a far point, although it also sounds like separate feature branches might be beneficial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do two things.  First, you have to tell lldb to suppress the SIGABRT signal that the `assert` delivers.  Do this by running:

```
(lldb) process handle SIGABRT -p 0
```

in lldb.  Normally SIGABRT is not maskable, so I was a little surprised this worked.  Maybe because this is a SIGABRT the process sends itself?  I don't think there's any guarantee suppressing SIGABRT's has to work in the debugger so YMMV, but it seems to currently.  Anyway, do this when you've hit the assert.

Then you need to forcibly unwind the assert part of the stack.  You can do that using `thread return`, which returns to the thread above the currently selected one w/o executing the code in that frame or any of the others below it.  So just select the frame that caused the assert, go `down` one frame on the stacks and do `thread return`.

Now when you `continue` you won't hit the abort and you'll be back in your code.

Comment: Might require a separate question but wondering what if I wanted to suppress the assert so it wouldn't hit again while I am running the app? Is there any command to prevent the assertion from being hit again?

Comment: assert itself is a macro, so there's no good way to catch the assert.  But the assert macro calls another function, so you could set an auto-continue breakpoint on that and add a command `thread return`.  That would work if nobody else in your app needs that function to have a valid value.